# Django: Error with Admin registration: AttributeError at / type object 'Page' has no attribute 'validate'

Tags: python, django

Not my first Django app, but can't see/figure out why I am getting the AttributeError with the Page model:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Funnel(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

    description  = models.CharField( 'Description', max_length=100 )
    shortname    = models.CharField( 'Single Word Identifier', max_length=30 )
    landing_page = models.ForeignKey('Page', verbose_name = 'Landing Page')
    signup_page  = models.ForeignKey('Page', verbose_name = 'Signup Page')
    deal         = models.ForeignKey('Deal')

class Deal(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

    description = models.CharField( 'Description', max_length=100 )
    shortname   = models.CharField( 'Single Word Identifier', max_length=30 )

class Page(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

    description = models.CharField( 'Description', max_length=100 )
    filename    = models.CharField( 'File Name', max_length=100 )
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from insights.models import Funnel, Deal, Page

class FunnelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('shortname', 'description', 'deal', 'deal_days', 'active')

admin.site.register(Funnel, FunnelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Deal, Page)
```

Triple-checking my other apps, notes.. tried moving things around in admin.py.. no luck. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `register` needs to be a `ModelAdmin`.

```
admin.site.register(Deal, Page)
#                           ^^^ remove this
```

Comment: Works, had to register Page separately. So, any subsequent models which we want available in the Admin should be added one by one. Thanks Yuji!